# how to create mysql view in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, view

how to create `mysql` view in `phpmyadmin`?

I executed following query in sql window of `phpmyadmin`:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED DEFINER = user SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `employees` 
                    AS select * from test.emp WITH LOCAL CHECK OPTION
```

But it is giving error:

**SQL query:** Documentation

```
CREATE
 ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED
 DEFINER = user
 SQL SECURITY DEFINER
 VIEW `employees`
 AS  select * from test.emp 
 WITH LOCAL  CHECK OPTION
```

**MySQL said:** Documentation

*#1046 - Aucune base n'a Ã©tÃ© sÃ©lectionnÃ©e*

When i simply run query "`select * from test.emp;`" it executes properly and on clicking create view it is creating view with options. But by syntax it is giving error.

Comment: Yes. View created. Actually i was not specifying database name of view. That's why it was giving error. Now executed correctly.